# how do you store a dynamical set of textboxs to an array in a c# winform

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

I'm currently trying to program what I thought was going to be a simple game, since I have already done it in a non-graphical environment (c++). Now im trying to reprogram in c# winform. In my first form the user inputs how many players are going to play in a range from 1 to 10. Depending on the users input on the first form determines how many labels and textboxs will be populated on my second form.

On my second form where the textboxs are populated on load, I am trying to take the name(s) the user or users put into the textbox or textboxs and store them into an array I can pass to my next form and use to display the users name when it is there turn to play.

```
private void playerNames_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string myOnload = null;

        if (myOnload == null)
        {
            TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[numPlayers];
            Label[] label = new Label[numPlayers];
            int labelX, labelY, textboxX, textboxY;

            labelX = 20;
            labelY = 22;
            textboxX = 70;
            textboxY = 20;

            for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
            {
                int labelCTR = i + 1;
                textBox[i] = new TextBox();
                textBox[i].Name = "player" + i;
                textBox[i].Text = "";
                textBox[i].Location = new Point(textboxX, textboxY);

                label[i] = new Label();
                label[i].Name = "player" + i;
                label[i].Text = "Player " + labelCTR;
                label[i].Location = new Point(labelX, labelY);

                labelY += 25;
                textboxY += 25;
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
            {
                this.Controls.Add(textBox[i]);
                this.Controls.Add(label[i]);
            }
        }
    }
```

The above code is how I make the form populate the textBoxs based on the user input for the value of the numPlayers variable.

```
private void submitPlayers_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] name = new string[numPlayers];
        //List<string> name = new List<string>();

        for (int i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
        {
            TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[numPlayers];
            //name[i] = textBox[i].Text; // first try and fail
            name[i] += textBox[i].Text; // my code currently crashes here
            //name.Add(textBox[i].Text); // it also crashes here if i try to switch from array to list


            for (i = 0; i < numPlayers; i++)
            { 
                int m = i+1;
                MessageBox.Show("Player " + m + " " + name[i], "testing");
            }
        }
```

The above code is where I'm trying to dump the textBoxs into an array so I can store them for later use on my next form. I added the messageBox at the end to try and test the array by making it dump one name per messageBox until all the names have been successfully dumped. When I finally get that to work, the for loop with the messageBox will be replaced with the code to open my next form and pass the name array to it. So each players turn will be a little more personalized with their name in the title bar of the form.

Comment: You can use list of textboxes, easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making the textboxes local to your loops, so you can't access the original textboxes from the second method (you are accessing a new array which you haven't populated).

This:

```
TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[numPlayers];
```

Declares a new variable and assigns a new array to it.

So declare them scoped to the class (where you are declaring `numPlayers`, for example), instead of on the method, and when creating the array, use:

```
textBox = new TextBox[numPlayers];
```

(notice that we aren't specifying the type, so here we are assigning the new array to an existing variable, instead of declaring a new variable)

In the second method, just remove the declaring line alltogether (the array is already declared, and has been created on the first method)

---

The reason it crashes is because you are doing:

```
TextBox[] textBox = new TextBox[numPlayers];
name[i] = textBox[i].Text;
```

So you are allocating an array of textboxes of size `numPlayers`, but you are not creating the textboxes themselves (notice that, in the first method, you are doing so, by doing `textBox[i] = new TextBox()`)... so when you try to access `textBox[i]` on the second method, you are accesing an unintialized variable.

Comment: Thank you, @Jcl that fixed my crashing problem. Now I just have to figure out why the messageBox loop is only dumping the first name, almost as if the array is not saving the other names.

Comment: The code runs instead of crashing, but when the code runs the messageBox loop it only dumps the first name. It keeps running the messageBox loop and increments ` "player " + [i] ` like it should, but where the ` name[i] ` section is in the messageBox line comes up blank on every messageBox  past the first one.

Comment: @SubZero oh, I see the problem... you are running the messagebox loop *inside* the other loop (and using the same variable name for both: `i`). Get the *messagebox-showing* loop **outside** the *name-array-filling* loop

Comment: I cant believe I did that, thank you so much. I have been racking my brain all weekend trying to figure out why it wasn't working. After moving that segment outside of the loop that saves the textboxes to the array it works like perfectly. Thank you so very much